# How to keep child browsers in the same session in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have a web application with strong authentication, and after successful log in to the application, I have a link to click, which opens a task in a child browser. When I perform all this manually in IE 11, everything works fine, but when I perform this using watir-webdriver, a child browser takes me to a authentication page, probably because a browser that was opened by watir does share the same session between parent and child browsers. Does anyone know how to keep all tabs of IE in the same session?
FYI I am using IEDriverServer 2.49, IE 11, Windows 7

Comment: There is an IE driver bug that describes a similar problem of [new window losing the session cookie](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1356).

Comment: Try using getNeededURL, then get(getNeededURL) instead of clicking

Comment: @SveatoslavCircel a click actually triggers ajax request, and there is no  `ahref` parameter of an element

Comment: Then try using javascript.